# How really flush cache in D7?

Tags: 7, caching

EDIT

My problem is that i have a module on a D6 website that should get some data from another website (a D7) but thoses data are old ones that should not exist.

The D7 site have a Forum. The last topics of the forum are set in a page with no theme :

```
function forum_topic_menu(){
  $items["lastopic/homepage"]=array(
    'title' => 'Forums',
    'page callback' => '_forum_topic_home',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
}

function _forum_topic_home(){
  global $language;
  $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
  ...
  $listeTopics = "request to get the last topics";
  $content = theme("forum_topic_block_hp",array("topics"=>$listeTopics));

  print $content;
}
```

The forum_topic_block_hp is a page with no theme, so the data are display just like that.

The D6 get the data wit a custom module :

```
function _getLastForum_contents(){
global $language;
$URLBLOCFORUM = "url of the D7 page";

$response = file_get_contents($URLBLOCFORUMCLUB);

return $response;
 }
```

On each website the performance module is activated and cache are clear every six hour, so i should have every six hours an update of the forum; But even if the D7 page is updated, the block on the D6 page isn't, the block keep to show the former page. But when i flush manually the cache on the D7 site, then that works.

So do someone know how properly refresh the cache programmatically or should i use another way to get the last topics from another website?

Comment: What do you mean "each have performance activated?"

Comment: ... and how is the block or the stuff added in the site ?

Comment: Links to modules you're using and screens of their configuration (and Drupal caching / aggregation config, too) may help. I'm afraid I have no idea what your setup looks like. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - *"The Golden Rule: Imagine You're Trying To Answer The Question"*. Would you be able to understand what you are talking about, if you would have no knowledge about your setup except what's in your question?

Comment: @Jimajamma i mean that the module performance run and cache is set on each page of the website.

Comment: @AyeshK I have a custom module that display a single block (with no cache). That module get the date from the page with the url and the file_get_contents function. I edit my post to show that.

Comment: @ Molot, i edit my post to be more precise. I do understand i am not clear, the problem just seem too weird.

Comment: @SavaryNicolas I think you should not rely on automatic cache clearance/storage then. 
When you file_get_contents the content from other site, explicitly set a cache (cache_set) for some time. Drupal will clear cache automatically. When showing block content, use a cache_get to see if cached, and refresh if cache is empty. 

An iframe based solution will also work I guess ?